# SetAppThreadPriority: setpriority failed with error 45

Tags: xcode, multithreading

Hello I have an issue with my app:

```
 SetAppThreadPriority: setpriority failed with error 45
```

I am using Xcode 6 and I am not sure if this is the issue.

Comment: https://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: I have the same problem, but remember that it's not allowed to write about the bugs in the beta program. @MatthiasBauch is right, you should ask there.

Comment: @tomatentobi OP did state that he/she was not sure if Xcode 6 was to blame or if it was something to do with his/her app. So, not specifically a bug discussion as much as a general inquiry as to the source of the problem, I too thought it was something wrong with my code.

Answer (score 3):

I am new to Xcode so perhaps this is expected behavior, but i found that i get this error if i have the GameScene.Swift file selected in the project navigator when i run the simulation. But if i have the top level folder selected it runs fine without this error.
By selected, i just mean clicked on so it's highlighted..

Other suggestions did not solve it for me.

Comment: Amazing. Probably is just a bug

Answer (score 0):

if you are using storyboard, go to Targets -> General and check the Main Interface property if your storyboard is selected.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confident this is a bug within the Xcode beta. I'd love to share why, but it's against Apple's TOS. There's nothing wrong with your code. You should submit a bug report to Apple: [bugreport.apple.com](http://bugreport.apple.com)

Answer (score -7):

You are not setting the thread priority for your NSOperation. Here is an example in Swift that gives the error you are seeing and one that doesn't. I'm assuming the same error message will appear if you are using Objective-C

Does

```
let backgroundOperation = BackGroundSillyness()
queue.addOperation(backgroundOperation)
backgroundOperation.completionBlock = {
    println("hello from completion")
}
println("hello from UI thread")
```

Doesn't

```
   let backgroundOperation = BackGroundSillyness()
    queue.addOperation(backgroundOperation)
    backgroundOperation.threadPriority = 0
    backgroundOperation.completionBlock = {
        println("hello from completion")
    }
    println("hello from UI thread")
```